# Display multiple images on multiple points using folium popup

Tags: python, dataframe, popup, geopandas, folium

I would like to plot my point data and display the unique images through a popup on my folium map. I have 67 plots, each with a different image assigned.

I have a `geopandas` point dataframe with the attribute `Path` which links to the relevant image path, ie: `C:/Users/Documents/GIS/Untitled Folder/photo1.jpg`.

I would like to create a loop which reads the 'image path' and plots the relevant image in the popup for each location.

I have imported my file as a `.shp`. `Photos` is my dataframe.

```
locations1 = Photos[['Y', 'X']]
locationlist1 = locations1.values.tolist()

path=Photos[['Path']]
pathlist=path.values.tolist()

for point in range(0, len(locationlist1)):
   png=Photos[pathlist].format()
   encoded = base64.b64encode(open(png, 'rb').read())
   html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format
   iframe = IFrame(html(encoded.decode('UTF-8')), width=400, height=350)
   popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=400)
   folium.Marker(locationlist1[point], tooltip=html, popup = pathlist[popup], icon=folium.Icon(color = 'purple')).add_to(m)

m
```

I am aware within my for loop I need to point to the image path but unsure how to read the file path for each point.

Answer (score 0):

- to create a working standalone code

  1. source flags of the world
  2. use *natural earth lowres* for geometry
- for each country source flag from file.  encode so that it works in an  HTML element
- create marker and popup for encoded image

#### source image files

- get flags of the world

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests, urllib
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile

# fmt: off
# download data set
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/zhongtr0n/country-flag-urls"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
dfs = {f.filename: pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f)) for f in zfile.infolist()}
# fmt: on

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("flags")
if not f.exists():
    f.mkdir()

for r in dfs["flags_iso.csv"].iterrows():
    flag_file = f.joinpath(f'{r[1]["Alpha-3 code"]}.gif')
    if not flag_file.exists():
        r = requests.get(r[1]["URL"], stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
        with open(flag_file, "wb") as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                fd.write(chunk)
```

#### solution

```
import folium
import base64, io
import geopandas as gpd
from PIL import Image

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
# change to centroid
world["geometry"] = world["geometry"].centroid
# define image path for each row
img_d = Path.cwd().joinpath("flags")
world["path"] = world["iso_a3"].apply(lambda c: str(img_d.joinpath(f"{c}.gif")))

# create folium map
m = world.explore()

# create markers with popups
for _, r in world.iterrows():
    lat = r['geometry'].y
    lon = r['geometry'].x
    path = r["path"]
    
    try:
        b = io.BytesIO()
        im = Image.open(path) # Your image here!
        im.save(b, format='PNG')
        b64 = base64.b64encode(b.getvalue())
        folium.Marker(location=[lat, lon], 
                      popup=f'<img src="data:image/png;base64,{ b64.decode("utf-8") }">').add_to(m)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        pass
m
```

[image]